# How can I change InvokeRepeating time in unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a slider in the pause menu which will have a min value of 1 and max of 5.
When I change it, the `InvokeRepeating` function maintains the same speed, but Debug.Log shows current slider value.

How can I change the `InvokeRepeating` rate?

Player.m1 is a float; when I give 5f or something like that to `InvokeRepeating` it works fine.

````cs
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Gen1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject rocks;

        int scr = 0;
        public int m=0;
        float n11=Player.m1;
        float sp;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            //if (Player.m1 == 5 || Player.m1==4) {
            InvokeRepeating ("CreateObstacle", Player.m1,5f);//Here speed handels
            //} else {
                //InvokeRepeating ("CreateObstacle", 4f, 5f);//Here speed handels
            //}
            Debug.Log ("current speed is afad"+Player.m1);
        }

        void Update()
        {
            //InvokeRepeating ("CreateObstacle", 4f, Player.m1); //Here speed handels
            //Debug.Log ("current speed is afad"+Player.m1);
        }

        void OnGui()
        {
            GUI.color = Color.black;
            GUILayout.Label ("Score is" + scr.ToString ());
        }

        void CreateObstacle()
        {
            Instantiate(rocks);
            Player.score += 1;
            Debug.Log ("current speed is "+sp);

        }

        void OnBecameInvisible() { 
            // Destroy the bullet 
            Destroy(this.rocks);
        } 
    }
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an `InvokeRepeating` is started, you can't change the repeat rate. You have to [Cancel the Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html) and start it again.... **Or**, you use the power of coroutines! `Invoke` and `InvokeRepeating` should be removed from the Unity API IMO...

```
public float sp = 5f ;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine( CreateObstacle(Player.m1) ) ;
}

IEnumerator CreateObstacle( float time )
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time) ;
    while( true )
    {
        Instantiate(rocks);
        Player.score += 1;
        Debug.Log ("current speed is "+sp);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sp) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works but i made some changes

Comment: [code]yield return new WaitForSeconds (time);
  while (true) {
   Instantiate (rocks);
   Player.score += 1;
   Debug.Log ("current speed is " + sp);
   if (Player.m1 == 5)
   yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
   else if(Player.m1==4)
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.5f);
   else if(Player.m1==3)
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
   else if(Player.m1==2)
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
   else
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (4);
   
   Debug.Log ("Setting speed");
  }
 }[code]

Comment: Personally, I don't like coroutines either. But until we have a better event driven solution, that's our best bet.